# Oversampling : SMOTE parameter 'ratio'

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, oversampling, imbalanced-data, imblearn

jupyter notebook got me error:

> **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ratio'

my code:

`smote = SMOTE(ratio = 'minority', random_state=10)`

Also try with: 
`smote = SMOTE(ratio = 0.5, random_state=10)`
but it gave me the same error message.

How to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the documentation here:
https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html
the argument 'ratio' does not exist.
the correct argument is 'sampling_strategy'. so in code:

```
smote=SMOTE(sampling_strategy='not minority',random_state=10) #equivalent to sampling_strategy=1.0 for binary classification, but also works for multiple classes
#or
smote=SMOTE(sampling_strategy=0.5,random_state=10) #only for binary classification
```

Comment: **ratio** is deprecated. Now **sampling_strategy** does the same thing as ratio used to do